# Using regex to match variables in a string

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match, using regex with groups, in java these scenarios but I am not very good with regex and don't understand how to match repeating things like these:

Text: **local var1, var2, var3 = 100**

I want to match to get all the lua variable names so my matches would be 'var1' and 'var2' and 'var3'

Text: **self.var1, self.var2 = 200**

Same as above but using self instead of local- I'd like matches of 'var1' and 'var2'

And lastly
Text: **var1, var2, var3 = 300**

I imagine I may be able to use the first regex for this, right? I'd like the matches to work for 1 or more matches so these all would work:

var1 = 10

var1, var2 = 10

self.v = 1

self.v1, self.v2 = 20

local v1,v2 = 10

local v1 = 30

I do not need all this in one big regex, 2 or 3 different patterns would work. (Hope this type of question is appropriate since I don't really have any code to show...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this should work

```
String input = "...Your input...";
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s*(?=[,=])").matcher(input);
while(m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: thanks, works well with a little tweaking for my purpose!